# Dynamically deleting a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to dynamically create and delete rails models. Creation works but not deletion.

I've tried deleting it as a Constant but it is still present as a rails subclass:

```
Object.send(:remove_const, :ModelToBeDeleted)

# Check it's gone from Object
Object.constants.include? :ModelToBeDeleted # => false

# But it is still in rails:
ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses
# returns 
[ModelToBeDeleted(....)]
```

I've then tried using the callback in the finisher, which does this when reloading in development:

```
ActiveSupport::DescendantsTracker.clear
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
```

But it has no effect.

Can anyone help me on how to do this?
Thanks
Nick

Comment: Are you doing this in code? or are you using the console?

Comment: I'm doing this in code. In the console reload! would work and I think ti does the clear actions shown above. I can't get the same effect in code.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are garbage collected the same way as regular objects - when there's no references to them.

Most common references are constants and instances, also there may be regular references. Make sure all references to the class are gone

```
class CLS; end
c = Class.new(CLS)
CLS.subclasses # => [#<Class:0x007fd64772dc68>]
obj = c.new
c = nil
GC.start
CLS.subclasses # => [#<Class:0x007fd64772dc68>]
obj = nil
GC.start
CLS.subclasses # => []
```

Comment: How can I find the references to the classes?

Comment: @nikmak that's a hard task, thinking over where it can be - is actually a good start, plus i'd advise to switch to unnamed classes, or write its `object_id` to log, in MRI you can get hack-style reference, for above class `ObjectSpace._id2ref(0x007fd64772dc68 >> 1)` will give you a reference, then you can iterate ObjectSpace in search for different kinds of references

Comment: I just investigated and realised I can't delete the object itself. I tried `object = nil` and `GC.start` but it is still there. Is that normal?

Comment: @nikmak it means that there's a reference left somewhere, for example model can have relations and objects lingering in associations. You really have to go over everything that can reference it